# DSC Extension - MSFT_xADDomainController Failing on Get-ADDomain PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, dsc

I am hitting an issue when trying to join a VM (Windows Server 2019) to a domain and promote it to a DC.  The deployment is being down via ARM Templates using the DSC extensions.  It is a single template that deploys both VMs and configures them as DCs so they are all using the same credentials etc.  I've tried the updated Active Directory DSC from [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/xActiveDirectory).

The error I am getting is:

```
"DSC Configuration 'CreateADBDC' completed with error(s). Following are the first few: Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running. PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_xADDomainController failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: Domain 'DOMAIN.CO.UK' could not be found. The SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed
```

The odd thing is I can login to the VM and join the domain through the UI and it works fine, likewise I can promote it via the UI and again that works.  The DNS settings are right and the primary DC is resolvable.

From what I can see is this command that is being run by the "Set-TargetResource" function within the MSFT_xADDomainController.psm1:

```
Get-ADDomain -Identity $DomainName -Credential $DomainAdministratorCredential
```

If I run this command on the VM I am trying to promote the command fails, the output from the failure is:

```
Get-ADDomain : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running
```

Which looks very similar to the error output from the DSC extension which is making me wonder if the actual issue is with the PowerShell Active Directory module.

Additional info:

**DSC Extension snipet**

```
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('dc2name'), '/CreateADBDC')]",
                    "apiVersion": "2019-03-01",
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', variables('dc2name'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions', variables('dc1name'), 'CreateADForest')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
                        "type": "DSC",
                        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.77",
                        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                        "settings": {
                            "WMFVersion": "latest",
                            "configuration": {
                            "url": "[concat(parameters('Artifacts Location'), '/dsc/CreateADBDC.zip')]",
                            "script": "CreateADBDC.ps1",
                            "function": "CreateADBDC"
                            },
                            "configurationArguments": {
                                "DomainName": "[parameters('Domain Name')]",
                                "DNSServer": "[variables('dc1ipaddress')]"
                            }
                        },
                        "protectedSettings": {
                            "configurationArguments": {
                                "adminCreds": {
                                    "UserName": "[parameters('Administrator User')]",
                                    "Password": "[parameters('Administrator Password')]"
                                    },
                                "SafeModeAdminCreds" :{
                                    "UserName": "[parameters('Administrator User')]",
                                    "Password": "[parameters('SafeMode Password')]"
                                    }   
                                },
                            "configurationUrlSasToken": "[parameters('Artifacts Location SAS Token')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
```

**CreateADBDC.ps1**

```
configuration CreateADBDC {
    Param (
        # Get deployment details
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$DNSServer,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$DomainName,

        # Credentials
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Admincreds,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$SafeModeAdminCreds,


        [Int]$RetryCount = 500,
        [Int]$RetryIntervalSec = 3
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration, xStorage, xNetworking, xActiveDirectory, xPendingReboot
    $Interface = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "Ethernet*" } | Select-Object -First 1
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$DomainCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("${DomainName}\$($Admincreds.UserName)", $Admincreds.Password)
    $features = @("AD-Domain-Services", "RSAT-ADDS-Tools", "RSAT-AD-AdminCenter")

    Node localhost {
        LocalConfigurationManager {
            ActionAfterReboot = 'ContinueConfiguration'
            ConfigurationMode = 'ApplyOnly'
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
        }

        xWaitforDisk Disk2 {
            DiskNumber       = 2
            RetryIntervalSec = $RetryIntervalSec
            RetryCount       = $RetryCount
        }

        xDisk ADDataDisk {
            DiskNumber  = 2
            DriveLetter = "F"
            DependsOn   = "[xWaitForDisk]Disk2"
        }

        WindowsFeatureSet Prereqs {
            Name                 = $features
            Ensure               = "Present"
            IncludeAllSubFeature = $true
        } 

        xDnsServerAddress DnsServerAddress {
            Address        = $DNSServer
            InterfaceAlias = $Interface.Name
            AddressFamily  = "IPv4"
            DependsOn      = "[WindowsFeatureSet]Prereqs"
        }

        xWaitForADDomain DscForestWait {
            DomainName           = $DomainName
            DomainUserCredential = $DomainCreds
            RetryCount           = $RetryCount
            RetryIntervalSec     = $RetryIntervalSec
            DependsOn            = "[WindowsFeatureSet]Prereqs"
        }

        xADDomainController BDC {
            DomainName                    = $DomainName
            DomainAdministratorCredential = $DomainCreds
            SafemodeAdministratorPassword = $SafeModeAdminCreds
            DatabasePath                  = "F:\NTDS"
            LogPath                       = "F:\NTDS"
            SysvolPath                    = "F:\SYSVOL"
            DependsOn                     = "[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait"
        }

        xPendingReboot RebootAfterPromotion {
            Name      = "RebootAfterDCPromotion"
            DependsOn = "[xADDomainController]BDC"
        }
    }
}
```

MSFT_xADDomainController.psm1 - [LINK](https://github.com/PowerShell/xActiveDirectory/blob/dev/DSCResources/MSFT_xADDomainController/MSFT_xADDomainController.psm1)

**DSC Log file output**

```
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:12Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress] Checking the DNS Server Address ...
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress] DNS Servers are not correct. Expected 10.x.x.250, actual 10.x.x.250 10.x.x.249 8.8.8.8
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress] in 0.7500 seconds.
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress] Checking the DNS Server Address ...
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress] DNS Servers are not correct. Expected 10.x.x.250, actual 10.x.x.250 10.x.x.249 8.8.8.8
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress] DNS Servers have been set correctly.
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress]  in 0.0940 seconds.
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[xDNSServerAddress]DnsServerAddress]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:13Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait] Checking for domain DOMAIN.CO.UK ...
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:14Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait] Found domain DOMAIN.CO.UK
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:14Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait] in 0.6790 seconds.
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:14Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Skip   Set      ]  [[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:14Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:14Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[xADDomainController]BDC]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:14Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[xADDomainController]BDC]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:15Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xADDomainController]BDC] Resolving 'DOMAIN.CO.UK' ...
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:57Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xADDomainController]BDC] Domain 'DOMAIN.CO.UK' is NOT present on the current node.
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:57Z] Settings handler status to 'transitioning' 
(C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.77.0.0\Status\0.status)
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:57Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[xADDomainController]BDC]  in 43.2480 seconds.
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:57Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[xADDomainController]BDC]
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:23:57Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xADDomainController]BDC] Resolving 'DOMAIN.CO.UK' ...
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:24:40Z] [ERROR] Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:24:40Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]:                            [[xADDomainController]BDC] Checking if domain 'DOMAIN.CO.UK' is present ...
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:25:22Z] [VERBOSE] [DC2]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[xADDomainController]BDC]  in 84.3140 seconds.
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:25:22Z] Settings handler status to 'transitioning' 
(C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.77.0.0\Status\0.status)
VERBOSE: [2019-03-17 22:25:22Z] [ERROR] PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_xADDomainController  failed to execute 
Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: Domain 'DOMAIN.CO.UK' could not be found.
```

Comment: you got any proof dns settings are right at the time of the extension running? what does your domain name resolve to from the bdc? can you grant dsc logs as well? what id you rerun same extension 20 minutes later?

Comment: DNS servers are set at VNET level, in the DSC log you can see that it queries the DNS settings and the right server is returned (it does complain about the additional DNS servers that it finds via the VNET).  The next step of the DSC is "dscForestWait", this successfully finds the domain.  Then it moves onto xADDomainController and that's where it all goes wrong.  I'll add the log to the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of head scratching I went back to basics and I found the culprit, it appears that MS have neglected a port or two from their documentation ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/179442/how-to-configure-a-firewall-for-domains-and-trusts)) for configuring firewalls to work with AD.  Yes, the ADWS (Active Directory Web Services) port is missing from the list.  Add a rule for TCP9389 and suddenly all my worries are far away. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the module code xWaitForADDomain is using a special function [Get-Domain](https://github.com/PowerShell/xActiveDirectory/blob/dev/DSCResources/MSFT_xWaitForADDomain/MSFT_xWaitForADDomain.psm1#L149), rather than Get-ADDomain cmdlet (which clearly errors out in your case), so you need to make this call (Get-ADDomain) to work on your vm. check the Active Directory Web Services as it suggests? run get-addomain with -debug switch

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've had a play with the file and tweaked it to remove the Get-ADDomain dependence.  The VM will now promote to a DC but the DSC is still reporting errors hence the deployment is marked as failed.  I've raised an issue on the DSC GitHub to see if they can shed light on the issue as I appear to be going around in circles now.  Its going to be easier to deploy hand at this rate :)

Comment: what errors its reporting? you should focus on why the get-addomain is not working right in your environment. probably means something is off